# How can I tell what a Microsoft FixIt actually does?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I am a software developer. *One* of my users (out of many) has an unusual problem with their computer, where they need to occasionally run a specific Microsoft FixIt, or they'll lose connectivity to my software. The software makes a network connection, which is severed permanently until they run this FixIt, which immediately restores connectivity. I am totally baffled as to how this is happening, and it is a unique issue.

The specific FixIt in question is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_update/). It is for Windows 7 only, as far as I can tell (the user is running Windows 7 32-bit).

How can I tell what operations this FixIt is actually performing on the system? What specific services is it stopping/starting/restoring? What files does it change? Maybe if I understood what it was doing, I could advise the user as to what might be happening on their system that breaks my software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows Update Fixit automates the actions described in the 'Let me fix it myself' section of [KB971058](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058). There's a lot in there that might be affecting your software.

Comment: How did you come across the association between that particular FixIt and that KB article? The link I provided doesn't link to that KB article, so what information did you use to correlate one to the other? Nice find, by the way.

Comment: @allquixotic I've been using that KB for years, before  the separate Fixits existed.

Comment: @allquixotic David Marshall is right. This Fixit and the KB971058 are identical. The original Fixit (when the service was just introduced) linked to the KB article, later that got replaced by the current 3 line summary of the actions taken. I've needed it a couple of times myself just like David.